# passing double quotes and brackets via parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scope defined in angularjs (1.x) that looks like this

```
$scope.report = { 
        resource: '/public/emplyACH', 
        params: { "employeeId": [78] }
    };
```

when I call it with console.log (`console.log(scope.parms)`)

I get this

`{employeeId: Array[1]`

but what I want is this:

`{ "employeeId": [78] }`

why can't I get it like that?

Comment: It's just how the console displays it, why's it matter?

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
var array = [78];
```

You have an array with a **single item** in it, the number `78`, and it's length is `1`.

What you see in the console is a representation of an array showing you `Array[length]`, meaning it's an array, and it's length is `1`.

You still have an array containing the number `78`, it's just how the browser shows it.

If you wanted an array with a length of `78`, then that would be something different, or if you wanted it as a string, which is likely as it seems to be an ID for an employee, you'd do

```
{ "employeeId": "[78]" }
```

Or why not remove the brackets, and use a number for the ID

```
{ "employeeId": 78 }
```

Comment: Note: this is just how the console shows the object, but you can do `console.log(JSON.stringify(report))` and it will be displayed exactly as it is

Comment: ok...I see what you mean...what about getting employeeId to stay in double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the escape character () \".
For more information check this:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp